# Changing which java file runs first when opening jar

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm not entirely sure how to word this but how would I go about changing which java file in my package is the first one to open when the compiled jar file is executed?

I'm also using netbeans if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can changed it in Netbeans. When you run the whole project in netbeans, the first class that is executed there is also the first class to be executed in the jar file built by Netbeans.

You can right click your project in the project window and select Properties. From the window that opens, select the run category in the left side. Then on the right side, there is a button to browse and select the file for the Main Class.

Comment: How would user3386295 go about that?

Answer (score 0):

The manifest indicates the Main-Class that runs when you execute a jar file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: This is the best of all the other answers. *except* that it is basically a link-only answer.  If you provide a little more context within the answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two (or more) classes with `public static void main`, click `File` | `Project properties` and in the `Categories` dialog, click `Run` and look for `Main Class:`. and then click `Browse...` to select which main class to start with.

(But I'm not sure this answers what you really want to do since once compiled with the chosen main class, there's no way to later have the `.jar` file run another class. If this doesn't answer your question, maybe a good question in return is, "What are you trying to do?")